# Getting the system information in shared hosting for the particular website only

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, system-administration

I have a client who gave me the FTP credentials server to upload the web files to the public_html folder and a pre-existing MySQL database to dump the tables of the website, only, without complete information of the server, as I know the server host the number of other website as well(shared hosting).

After uploading the web files to the public_html directory and dumping the MySQL tables to the given database, When I browse the newly created website. It is too too much slow, even it says the resource limit is exceeded, with 3 or 4 more request to the server, and the website is created using the wordpress.

As in the most of the shared hosting the service provider provide the cpanel, which display the system status and the resource usages for each website, as the Server has not any c panel software installed (sysadmin use the CLI method) to view the resource usage by the each website.

I also create the `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` script to view the server information, but I couldn't get any clue from the output of this script.

Is there any php scripts which can show the information about the Bandwidth usage, CPU usage, ram usage, memory usage/allocated by php/mysql by the particular website so that we can put that script in the root directory of the website and execute it by calling it from the browser.  If No is there any other alternative way to view the server resource usage by this particular website. OR Should I need to contact the server administrator about this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact the server administrator about this.

If it's a shared hosting service, you can't access files and directories outside the one that has been assigned for you to use and host your files.

In order to know the server load and resources you would need to access UNIX files outside your directory; otherwise you would need to access CLI on that server. As far as I understand you can't.

In addition, if a shared web hosting service is having performance issues, it should be the machine's administrator concern, not yours.
You should alert the machine's owner and if you still can't get to solve the problem just change hosting provider as the provider is probably overselling.